# Hi, I am using Specflow and extentReport. How do I print the pending steps to my extent report?

Tags: specflow

I used the following code but the pending steps are not shown in the extent report. Is there a way to get the pending steps printed in the extent report?Thanks.

Code 1:

```
if (ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioExecutionStatus.ToString() == "StepDefinitionPending")
{
    if (stepType == "Given")
        scenarioName.CreateNode<Given>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
    else if (stepType == "When")
        scenarioName.CreateNode<When>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
    else if (stepType == "Then")
        scenarioName.CreateNode<Then>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
}
```

I also tried this code below, but is getting null pointer exception:

Code 2:

```
    PropertyInfo pInfo = typeof(ScenarioContext).GetProperty("TestStatus", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);//Getting Null value in PropertyInfo
            MethodInfo getter = pInfo.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
            object TestResult = getter.Invoke(ScenarioContext.Current, null);

  if (TestResult.ToString() == "StepDefinitionPending")
            {
                if (stepType == "Given")
                {
                    scenario.CreateNode<Given>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
                }                    
                else if (stepType == "When")
                {
                    scenario.CreateNode<When>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
                }                    
                else if (stepType == "Then")
                {
                    scenario.CreateNode<Then>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
var pendingDef = ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioExecutionStatus.ToString();

if (pendingDef == "StepDefinitionPending")
        {
         if (stepType == "Given")

scenario.CreateNode<Given>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
                else if (stepType == "When")
scenario.CreateNode<When>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
                    else if (stepType == "Then")
scenario.CreateNode<Then>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `TestStatus` with `ScenarioExecutionStatus` in your Hooks class:

```
PropertyInfo pInfo = typeof(ScenarioContext).GetProperty("ScenarioExecutionStatus",BindingFlags.Instance |BindingFlags.NonPublic);
MethodInfo getter = pInfo.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
object TestResult = getter.Invoke(ScenarioContext.Current, null);
```

Because, Specflow has changed the internals of the class.